# Merge multiple lines of JSON to a string using Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have an input JSON like this
[Show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeoKZ.png)

I want to use Mule4 to convert this JSON to a string like this:

`01/09/2301 1755: This is test line 1\n01/09/2301 1755: This is test line 2`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please use text instead of images while asking questions. It helps reader to be apne to copy the required details easily for solving the problem.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You just need to map each element of the array into a string. Then you can concatenate all the elements of the array with a separator using the joinBy() function. If you need to convert the date format just use the appropriate date time format conversion.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload 
    map ( $.key1 as Date {format: INPUTDATEFORMAT} as String {format: OUTUTDATEFORMAT} ++ ": " ++ $.key2)  
    joinBy "\n"
```

Comment: Minor edit: use `output text/plain` and this answer works

Comment: What doesn't work as is? It will always return a string, whatever the output is JSON, Java or text/plain.

Comment: As is I mean other than the format for the date conversions (INPUTDATEFORMAT, OUTUTDATEFORMAT) that are not part of the question (merging lines) and the question doesn't provide them either.